# spatie/laravel-newsletter doesn't work on laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravelcollective

Here is the image below

[See  the image of composer command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T64m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the latest version is to be used on 5.5.

You can pull an older version if you want:

`composer require spatie/laravel-newsletter 3.7.0`